# Questions on structural eng drawing for egress window

Tags: basement, windows, structural, engineering, egress

I am installing an egress window in my basement to make it a legal bedroom. I am going to be doing most of the work myself (outside of cutting the concrete) but doing it by the book (permits, inspections, etc). I hired a structural engineer to do the drawings. I will try to follow his drawings to the T, but there are a few things I am unclear on, highlighted in the drawing.

1. Did the engineer intentionally not include threaded rod for the header and I'm not seeing how it's secured? Or was that an oversight?
2. I don't fully understand the engineer's vision for securing the threaded rods to the vertical structural supports.
3. I have no idea what the symbol means where the vertical support and the header meet (maybe that will answer question #2?)

[image: Structural Engineer's Drawings]

Comment: My guess is that the header sits on the jamb legs, so doesn’t need any rod securing. But my guess doesn’t really matter — get back with the engineer and ask them all of these questions. It’s all part of their job.